# In Ruby, is there a better way of selecting a constant (or avoiding the constant altogether) based on an incoming string of the same name?

Tags: ruby, architecture

Not sure the title fully describes the problem/question I'm trying to ask, sorry.

One of my fellow developers has created classes as such:

```
class Widget
  attr_accessor :model_type
  ...
end
```

and:

```
class ModelType
  MODEL1 = "model1"
  MODEL2 = "model2"
  MODEL3 = "model3"
end
```

Now he wants me to convert a retrieved string `"MODEL1"` to the constant. So that when he is referencing that model elsewhere he can use `ModelType::MODEL1` **(EDIT: The incoming string will be the name of the constant exactly)**.  Obviously I've got to convert from the string I'm being given with something like the following:

```
case model_type
  when 'MODEL1'
    @model_type = ModelType::MODEL1
  ...
end
```

I feel like this is clunky, so I'd like to know if there is a better DRYer way of providing this kind of functionality.

Comment: it might be useful to mention the kind of model name strings you would actually use instead of `MODEL1` as there is some neat stuff you can do with converting to and from symbols, capitalization, pluralization, etc..

Comment: Thanks Anurag, will update, essentially ModelType::MODEL1 will exactly match "MODEL1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>> ModelType.const_get("MODEL1")

=> "model1"
```

[Module const_get() rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.src/M001689.html)